How to break out of if statement at any point with key press
I'm trying to make a bot for a game (no native leaderboard or competitions) where the bot will execute a sequence of moves based on time and position. Sometimes these sequences will be very long and I want to be able to break out of the if statement with a key press at any point, if something goes wrong instead of waiting for the entire sequence to finish out.
I found something that helps here: How can I check for a key press at any point during a loop? but it kills the whole process, instead of just breaking out of the if statement.
def sequence():

    keys = ["w","a","s","d","w","a","s","d"]

    while True:

        # start code
        if keyboard.is_pressed("f1"):

            for i in keys:
                pyautogui.keyDown(i)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                pyautogui.keyUp(i)
                time.sleep(0.1)


def main():
    p = Process(target=sequence)
    p.start()
    # this loop runs in parallel with the sequence loop, constantly checking
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break
    # force the sequence loop to stop immediately, without finishing the current iteration
    p.kill() # I assume this is where it needs to be changed?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I want the while loop to always run, but I'd like to be able to break out of the if statement at any point.

Does this answer your question? How can I check for a key press at any point during a loop?

maybe you should change code in bot - it should check keys after every move. OR it should check some global variable after every move and eventually exit code if not running: return. And other code should set running = False when you press key. But if you use Process then it may need to use queue and it should check (after every move) if there is message in queue.

@ReeceHarris it does not answer my question. I included a link to that question within my post, and I specified that that code killed the program, which I do not want

@Vee yh but all you have to do is modify that code to get what you want, unless you want someone to just give you the code,

For Process it many need to use queue to send message which will stop loop.
(for threading it should also work).
Something like this - but I didn't test it.
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
# from queue import Queue  # for `threading`

def sequence(queue):  # <--- get queue

    keys = ["w","a","s","d","w","a","s","d"]

    while True:

        # start code
        #if not queue.empty() and queue.get() == 'start':
        if keyboard.is_pressed("f1"):

            for i in keys:
                if not queue.empty():
                    msg = queue.get()
                    if msg == 'stop'
                        break   # if you want to stop only for-loop
                    if msg == 'quit'
                        return  # if you want to stop all code and exit process
                pyautogui.keyDown(i)
                # if not queue.empty(): 
                # ... code ...
                time.sleep(0.5)
                # if not queue.empty(): 
                # ... code ...
                pyautogui.keyUp(i)
                # if not queue.empty(): 
                # ... code ...
                time.sleep(0.1)

def main():
    queue = Queue
    
    p = Process(target=sequence, args=(queue,))  # it has to be comma in brackets `( , )` to create tuple.
    p.start()
    
    # this loop runs in parallel with the sequence loop, constantly checking
    while True:
        #if keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):
        #    queue.put('start')
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            queue.put('stop')
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            queue.put('quit')
            p.join()  # wait for end of process
            break
         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

You could even use queue to send sequence - this way it could run different sequences.
